# Proving a statement to be true using a statement that is sometimes true

Tags: generating-functions, formal-proofs

I am asking this question because I am unfamiliar with proofs and want to ask this question through an example:

If |x| < 1 then the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1-x)^{-(N+1)}$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 
N + n\\ 
n
\end{pmatrix}$. (Using the extended binomial theorem)

Which is equivalent to the coeffiicient of ${x^n}$ in $(1-x)^{-1} \cdot (1-x)^{-N}$.
$(1-x)^{-1} \cdot (1-x)^{-N} = (1+x+x^2 + x^3...)\cdot (1-x)^{-N}$. The Coefficient of $x^n$ here is $\sum_{j = 0}^{ n}\begin{pmatrix}
N + j - 1\\ 
j
\end{pmatrix}$. Because you have the $x^n$ term from $(1-x)^{-N}$ multiplied by 1, the $x^{n-1}$ term multiplied by $x^2$... etc till the $x^0$ term multipled by $x^n$.

Therefore you can say that $\begin{pmatrix} 
N + n\\ 
n
\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{j = 0}^{ n}\begin{pmatrix}
N + j - 1\\ 
j
\end{pmatrix}$.

To me it seems that the above statement is always true. However when proving it we assumed that |x| < 1. So are we allowed to prove statements using conditional statements. Or is it only allowed in this case because the final expression had no x in it?

Comment: This looks to me like a generating function using formal power series and so does not require convergence

Comment: @Henry . I'm not so sure about that. Suppose somehow we arrived at $A(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$ and $B(x)=\sum_n b_nx^n$ and suppose we have "If both series converge then $A(x)=B(x)$", but $a_n=n!$ and  $b_n=(2n)!$. Then $A(x), B(x)$ exist only when $x=0$, and $a_n\ne b_n$ for $n>0$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet - I am saying nothing about convergence.  But if you had a generating function for $x!$ ([OEIS A000142](https://oeis.org/A000142) suggests several expressions) then you could multiply it by another generating function such as $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to get a new generating function for a different sequence even though it does not converge for any $x\not=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proved that the coefficient of $x^n$ for $(1-x)^{-(N+1)}$ can be expressed in two different forms when $|x|<1$.

If two power series have the same value in an interval they have both the same coefficients. So you proved the combinatorial identity because then also the coefficient of $x^n$ must be the same, the fact that $|x|<1$ has no influence in this case.

Comment: The influence of $|x|<1$ is that if two power series in $x$ converge to the same value for every $x\in (-1,1)$ then they have the same co-efficients.

Comment: yes @DanielWainfleet, I meant that any other value would have been the same i.e. $|x|<2$